# Angular 8: FormArray.clear() does not clear my FormArray

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a nested FormGroup with the following declaration:

```
const invoiceFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  invoiceMethod: [0, [Validators.required]],
  data: this.formBuilder.array([]),
});
```

and then

```
this.settingsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  invoiceForm: invoiceFormGroup,
  ...
});
```

I pass `this.settingsForm.invoiceForm` into a component using an `@Input()` parameter

In my component when populating (and repopulating) the formgroup with FormControls I try the following

```
const fa = this.formGroup.get('data') as FormArray;
fa.clear();
```

this doesn't clear `fa`. It's just the same before and after the `.clear()`

It's the same if I try to do this:

```
(this.formGroup.get('data') as FormArray).clear();
```

Can anyone guide me in the right direction? There must be something basic I'm missing...

Comment: You can manually clear each FormArray element by calling the removeAt(i) function in a loop.

clearFormArray = (formArray: FormArray) => {
  while (formArray.length !== 0) {
    formArray.removeAt(0)
  }
}

Comment: You can replace whole FormArray with a new one.


clearFormArray = (formArray: FormArray) => {
  formArray = this.formBuilder.array([]);
}

Comment: Can you please specify what all are the components that you have for forms? Maybe create a Sample StackBlitz replicating the issue? It would really help :)

Comment: Okay as it turns out it's all due to a formGroup.valueChanges.subscribe that I have. If I unsubscribe before doing my formGroup manipulation it works as expected. The .clear() works. This just seems like a bit of a hack to me. If anyone can offer a better solution I'll be happy to hear it.

Comment: Again, some things are a bit unclear from what you've mentioned in your question. Can you please [fork this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pk4jaf) and implement a minimal Stackblitz as a starting point to work with?

Comment: I got it working now. I guess it was just my misunderstanding of when the valueChanges on a formGroup was fired.